# App crashes on device and while using instruments only

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am encountering a strange behaviour, my app runs smoothly on simulator but crashes on device.
Also when i try to detect leaks using instruments it just crashes on both simulator and device.
I am totally stuck as i am not even able to generate any error message on console, also NSZombieEnabled is on in the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two possible reasons for the behavior you describe:

1. device is short on memory; (but you would see some processing in this case)
2. your app uses a newer SDK than what you have installed on your device (like using the SDK 5 twitter framework and then running your app on an SDK 4 device).

Specifically, in case 2, you would not see any log messages because the app would fail as soon as it tries to load the missing framework in memory.

In any case, inspect the device log in Xcode Organizer window to have more info about the crash. This is the only way you can understand what is happening.

Comment: also if the wire is attached with the device it never crashes and if I use it independently it gets!!
Also i am using 3GS having only 128MB of RAM!

Comment: could you attach the crash log from the organizer window in xcode?

Comment: yes I checked in that but error log was not clearly telling me the actual problem...actually by mistake i was using [super dealloc] before releasing all other properties...so it was the problem!thanks anyways